# App architecting: multiple view controller storyboard v one view controller with views reloading?

Tags: ios, iphone, architecture, uistoryboard

I am working on an app that has a lot of different views and does not fall under any of apples predefined controller styles.
What should I opt in for, a multiple view controller storyboard or a single view controller and load and dismiss views on it?

Comment: What do u mean by "does not fall under any of apples predefined controller styles"? A little bit confused.

Comment: I mean I am having to use a custom view controller each time instead of say a table view controller or a tabbed view controller.

Comment: I think you are talking about set view controller class in Storyboard right?

Comment: Yup.please reread my question. I think you will get it now.